# How to get the intersection of multiple nested lists?

Tags: python, list, set

I am playing with python and wonder how to get the intersection of multiple nested lists.

```
list1 = [[10, 1], [200, 2], [300, 9], [400, 1], [500, 1]]
list2 = [[22, 1], [200, 2], [300, 9], [900, 1], [660, 1], [500, 1]]
list3 = [[30, 1], [200, 2], [300, 0], [400, 1], [500, 1]]
```

Each list contains multiple small lists, each small list contains two integers. The first integer  of each small list is different in each list.

Now, if  the first integer appears in each list , then keep it, sum the second integer.

Then the result should be [[200,6],[300,18],[500,3]]

A friend solved this problem:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = [[100, 1], [200, 2], [300, 99], [400, 1], [500, 1]]
list2 = [[22, 1], [200, 2], [300, 9], [900, 1],[1000, 1], [500, 1]]
list3 = [[30, 1], [200, 2], [300, 0], [400, 1], [500, 1]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3)

df4 = df1.merge(df2, on=0, how='inner')

df5 = df4.merge(df3, on=0, how='inner')

df6 = df5.copy()
df6['sum'] = df6.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
list4 = df6[[0, 'sum']].values.tolist()

print(list4)
```

When the data is huge, the running speed is slow. I wonder if there is any method that can use "set" to speed up the speed?

Answer (score 3):

> Each list contains multiple small lists, each small list contains two integers. The first integer of each small list is different in each list.

I'd suggest converting your nested lists to dictionaries, which seem to make *way* more sense here -- not just for this operation, but for working with the data in general. Then, all you need is a simple dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> d1, d2, d3 = dict(list1), dict(list2), dict(list3)
>>> d1
{10: 1, 200: 2, 300: 9, 400: 1, 500: 1}
>>> {k: d1[k] + d2[k] + d3[k] for k in d1 if k in d2 and k in d3}
{200: 6, 300: 18, 500: 3}
```

Or the same as a nested list comprehension, if you really need lists:

```
>>> [[k, d1[k] + d2[k] + d3[k]] for k in d1 if k in d2 and k in d3]
[[200, 6], [300, 18], [500, 3]]
```

About running time: After creating the dicts in O(n), the `if k in d2 and k in d3` checks are O(1) for an overall complexity of O(n), which should be about as fast as it gets.

---

About suggestion from comments: Using `d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()` works, too, but does not seem to be any faster (a bit slower in fact, for 1000 elements with 25% overlap).

```
>>> d1, d2, d3 = ({random.randrange(1000): random.randrange(1000) for _ in range(1000)} for _ in range(3))                                                              
>>> len(set(d1) & set(d2) & set(d3))                                                                                              
259
>>> %timeit {k: d1[k] + d2[k] + d3[k] for k in d1 if k in d2 and k in d3}                                                                                               
84.2 µs ± 1.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit {k: d1[k] + d2[k] + d3[k] for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()}                                                                                       
117 µs ± 817 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: `for k in d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()` would also work.

Comment: @SayandipDutta and would be much more efficient

Comment: @Nick How so? It would still iterate all the keys in `d1` once, and on top create 2 intermediate `sets`, or not? And the lookup is O(1).

Comment: Because you only compute `d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()` once instead of searching `d2` and possibly `d3` for every key in `d1`

Comment: @Nick Do you mean because of C speed vs Python speed? That's the only potential advantage I see.

Comment: @tobias_k, Kelly Bundy Mmmm... yeah, I was still thinking of lists, not dictionaries. Interesting to see the timing information. I tried the same thing for a length of 10000 and found that using `d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()` was marginally faster; but then at 100000 it was slower again. I guess that's what you get with random data...

Comment: @Nick Another option: `set(d1).intersection(d2, d3)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I had assumed that would be how `d1.keys() & d2.keys() & d3.keys()` would work internally.

Comment: @Nick It's at least *somewhat* different and I think I got times between the two earlier ways. But it does seem to work less differently than I had hoped, yes.